# Is there a way to display the user input (E.g. Name) in the next box in Applescript? Example: Hello there, Jimmy

Tags: applescript

```
set userName to display dialog "What's your name?" default answer "Name" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
if the button returned of the result is "OK" then display dialog "Hi there,  "
```

At the end where it says Hi there, I want it to say the user input after. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you…
I wrapped the code with a try command.  Doing this will allow for your AppleScript to continue executing any additional code, if the user chooses “Cancel”

```
try
    set userName to text returned of (display dialog "What's your name?" default answer ¬
        "Name" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2)
    
    display dialog "Hi there,  " & userName
end try
```

Comment: You can thank me by up voting and or choosing my answer as the accepted solution.